# How to integrate this (probability)?

Tags: calculus, probability

> Find $f(y)$ given$$f(x,y)=c\cdot\exp\left(-\frac{x^2-yx+y^2}2\right);\ x, y \in \mathbb{R}.$$

My approach:$$f(y)=\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}c·\mathrm{e}^{-\frac{x^2-yx+y^2}2}\,\mathrm dx$$
But I don't know how to integrate this.

Comment: $x^2-xy+y^2=\left(x-\frac{y}{2}\right)^2+\frac{3y^2}{4}$.

Comment: Using the same letter, $f$, to stand for two different functions in one problem is asking for trouble.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have
 $\frac{x^2-xy+y^2}{2}=(\frac{x}{\sqrt{2}}-\frac{y}{2\sqrt{2}})^2+\frac{3.y}{8}$

$f(y)=\int^{+\infty}_{-\infty}c. e^{-(\frac{x}{\sqrt{2}}-\frac{y}{2\sqrt{2}})^2-\frac{3.y}{8}}dx$

$f(y)=c .e^{\frac{-3y^2}{8}}\int^{+\infty}_{-\infty} e^{-(\frac{x}{\sqrt{2}}-\frac{y}{2\sqrt{2}})^2}dx$

we  pose:$t=\frac{x}{\sqrt{2}}$

$f(y)=\sqrt{2}.c .e^{\frac{-3y^2}{8}}\int^{+\infty}_{-\infty} e^{-(t)^2}dt$

$\int^{+\infty}_{-\infty}\int^{+\infty}_{-\infty}e^{-t^2-z^2}dtdz=\int^{2\pi}_0\int^{+\infty}_0re^{-r^2}drd\theta
 =2\pi \Bigg[\frac{-e^{-r^2}}{2}\Bigg]^{+\infty}_0=\pi$

then :$\int^{+\infty}_{-\infty}e^{-t^2}dt=\sqrt{\pi}$

So:$f(y)=\sqrt{2\pi}.c.e^{\frac{-3y^2}{8}}$

Answer (score 0):

Just as [NCh](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/413376/nch) stated, you can complete squares, so you have to solve the following integral.

$$g(y) = c. e^{\frac{3y^2}{4}} \int^{\infty}_{\infty} e^{-\left(x - \frac{y^2}{2} \right)^{2}} dx$$

This integral is well known you can google it up, but you can use a neat trick that is to take it to the form of a Normal dist.

The pdf for a normal dist with $\mu = \frac{y^2}{2}, \sigma = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ is:

$$h \left(x|\mu = \frac{y^2}{2}, \sigma = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \right) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi \left( \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)^{2}}} e^{-\frac{\left(x - \frac{y^2}{2} \right)^{2}}{2.\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)^{2}}}$$ 
$$h \left(x|\mu = \frac{y^2}{2}, \sigma = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \right) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}} e^{\left(x - \frac{y^2}{2} \right)^{2}}$$

So going back to your problem, we can rewrite it:

$$g(y) = c. e^{\frac{3y^2}{4}} \sqrt{\pi} \int^{\infty}_{\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}e^{-\left(x - \frac{y^2}{2} \right)^{2}} dx$$

Where $\int^{\infty}_{\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}e^{-\left(x - \frac{y^2}{2} \right)^{2}} dx = 1$ since it's integrating a pdf over the whole space.
Consequently,

$$g(y) = c\sqrt{\pi} e^{\frac{3y^2}{4}} $$